# Is their any software that tracks the performance of your team over time with internal A/B testing of changes?

Tags: software-development, project-management

So for example:

I am a software team lead and I want to test whether having our team do TDD will increase code quality, less bugs etc

I'm thinking the best way is to track outputs like the above over time. Before and after the team does TDD. Something like A/B tests but internally for your own developers and team instead of for users.

Same thing for meetings as well, i.e seeing if we can reduce the number of meetings we have and have a greater output.

Obviously I need to track this over time and convince higher up that TDD and/or less meetings is actually a good thing.

Is their any software that will help do this or will I just have to manually track it myself in spreadsheets.
I know JIRA has some type of tracking/reporting system but as far as I am aware it's more for estimate breakdowns and such.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to track actual output (customer benefits). This is hard, as you can't easily quantify them.

The more tracking the more overhead, so the slower the team will go.

Individual tracking will lead to perverse incentives, and poorer team performance: What is good for one persons performance review, is often bad for the team.

Start with other Agile methods: e.g. shorter cycles, and kanban (make is visible) boards.

With kanban (make it visible), things become visible. This and shorter cycles will probably solve most of you problems. It you implement these, then you will end up inventing the rest, when you are ready.

As for tools: A large white board. These outperform software tools.

As for will TDD help: Yes. Knowing that code is working is the best way to know that code is working. Knowing what success looks like, is the best way to know what success looks like. Quickly trying your success criteria, is the quickest way to see if you success criteria are any good. (See also the video by Bob Martin ­— the transformation priority premise.)